# Prometheus timestamps

Tags: timestamp, prometheus

I wrote an exporter which exposes timestamp next to the metric like:

```
test_load_min{app="web01"} 1 1483228810000
test_load_min{app="db01"} 2 1483228820000
test_load_min{app="email01"} 3 1483228830000
```

According to https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/exposition_formats/ this should be fine for Prometheus, but querying test_load_min in Prometheus UI returns empty result. Same without timestamps works fine. Anyone has an idea what's wrong there?

Answer (score 5):

The timestamp `1483228810000` converts back to January of this year.

Prometheus omits time series from query results if the timestamp for which the query is executed is more than 5 minutes away from the nearest sample.

It is also not advised to use timestamps in this way.

Comment: Yes, the timestamp is supposed to be Sun, 01 Jan 2017 00:00:10 GMT. I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, I try to import bunch of historical data into Prometheus for trending etc. How to get those data into Prometheus the right way? Is the 5 min omit configurable?

Answer (score 3):

Timestamps are not designed for the uploading of historical data.

There's a plan to add support for bulk historical uploads, tracked [here](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/535). The issue is still open for now though.

In the meantime, you could look at [promqueen](https://github.com/Cleafy/promqueen) which claims to solve this problem (though not for influxdb).

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert into ms. Once you are able to do, timestamp can be parsed.

For example:

```
timestamp = int(float(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()) * 1000)
```